# How to define an object of specific functions as a type or an interface?

Tags: typescript, function, object, interface, typescript-typings

I've attempted to look at other [similar questions](/questions/14662995/typescript-array-of-functions), but most of them appear to be defining arrays instead of objects.

I'm mostly new to Typescript as a whole, and am still trying to wrangle some of the concepts, having both experience in C# and JavaScript.

I'm making an object that is a collection of one or more named functions in an object. Each function accepts an array of strings, or multiple strings, as the following definition:

```js
define function PluginCommand(argv: array, ...args:string[]): number;
```

Now, how can I assign multiple of these `PluginCommand`s to a (preferably) defined object where the key can be any valid string?

Comment: Looking for `Record<string, PluginCommand>` perhaps? Equivalently: `{[key: string]: PluginCommand}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like:

```
interface Foo {
  bar: (args: Array<string>) => number;
}
```

If you want the key to be any string, do:

```
interface Foo {
  [key: string]: (args: Array<string>) => number;
}
```

Comment: How would this work for an object of multiple elements? like `{a:PluginCommand,b:PluginCommand...}`?

Comment: Given the above interface "Foo", and the function "PluginCommand", you could just do:

`const myObject: Foo = { a: PluginCommand, b: PluginCommand }`

Comment: Ah, yes, I understand now. Thank you.